# WPF Window eventhandler

Tags: c#, wpf

So we know that if you attach an event handler, we should remove it at some point if the object is not being used anymore. How does this work for Window objects?

Take for example, the Window's `Loaded` event, or `Closing` event. If we register the EventHandlers to handle these events in the `Initialize` method, why don't we ever unregister them?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. It's only really important if you're subscribing to an event on an object that you want to be GC'd. The event subscription can stop that from happening and will eat away at your memory. I usually just override the OnLoaded(), OnClosing(), etc. methods instead of attaching to events anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not a big deal. Usually you subscribe to the event in the derived class itself, so you will not cause the instance to linger in memory because of a stray event handler subscription. Also you will need the `Closing` event handler until the very end of the Window's lifetime, there is no point in unsubscribing from it.

Comment: Oh I get it, the event is subscribed to the instance itself. So what happens when I set the variable that is holding the reference to the Window instance to null?

Comment: @States: Then that will not do anything yet because the `Application` is being mean by having a [`Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) list :P

Comment: How the heck does that work? Lol, if you set a reference to null, shouldn't it go *poof*?

Comment: @States: The window is probably added to the list via the `Window` constructor which is always called implicitly. And no, that is probably one of the reasons why the WPF framework keeps track of all windows in the application: To prevent unwanted garbage collection of still opened windows.